Using Macros BizTalk 2020 Office 365 adapter
Can we use macros in BizTalk 2020 send adapter for Office 365.
I tried %SourceFileName% and it wasn't working, Also trying to input the service account details in to the port but it was recognizing the credentials of logged in person for sending emails using O365 adapter.

Have you configured BizTalk TMS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/configure-biztalk-server#configure-biztalk-tms  That is required before it can use authentication tokes with Office 365. Where are you trying to use the Macro?  For an email attachment?  I don't think you can use a Macro for that.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have configured TMS.  I   am trying to use %SourceFileName% macro in the subject line to mention received file name like we used to do it using SMTP adapter.

That adapter does not support it, and I wouldn't really expect it to, as an email can have multiple attachments.
You will have to create an Orchestration that get the ReceivedFileName and set it in the MIME message properties, similar to How Set Attachment Name to Show Properly in Outlook
